# How to translate byte escape sequence text to bytes in python (prepend with 'b') from string input - which encoding is proper for that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bin

I've searched many websites, stackoverflow's replies, but have not found exact solution with my trouble, in example:

- [When creating bytes with "b" prefix before string, what encoding does python use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63214198/when-creating-bytes-with-b-prefix-before-string-what-encoding-does-python-use)
- [How to encode string to bytes in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227005/how-to-encode-string-to-bytes-in-python)

My example – I can't understand what encoding will give same result as phrase preceded by with 'b' on escaped string:

```py
>>> txt_bz = b'BZh91AY&SY^\x85\xab\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x81\x80\x02\x02\x1c  \x000\xc0\x08a\xa5\x1a\x03\x0b\xb9"\x9c(H/B\xd5\xe9\x00'
>>> txt_cmp = bytes('BZh91AY&SY^\x85\xab\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x81\x80\x02\x02\x1c  \x000\xc0\x08a\xa5\x1a\x03\x0b\xb9"\x9c(H/B\xd5\xe9\x00', 'utf-8')
>>> txt_cmp==txt_bz
False
>> txt_cmp = bytes('BZh91AY&SY^\x85\xab\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x81\x80\x02\x02\x1c  \x000\xc0\x08a\xa5\x1a\x03\x0b\xb9"\x9c(H/B\xd5\xe9\x00', 'unicode-escape')
>>> txt_cmp==txt_bz
False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare solution:

```py
>>> txt_bz = b'BZh91AY&SY^\x85\xab\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x81\x80\x02\x02\x1c  \x000\xc0\x08a\xa5\x1a\x03\x0b\xb9"\x9c(H/B\xd5\xe9\x00'
>> txt_cmp = bytes('BZh91AY&SY^\x85\xab\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x81\x80\x02\x02\x1c  \x000\xc0\x08a\xa5\x1a\x03\x0b\xb9"\x9c(H/B\xd5\xe9\x00', 'latin1')
>>> txt_cmp==txt_bz
True
```